# How to load data in spinner in Android?

Tags: java, android

I tried to load data into my spinner. But it doesn't works well. I don't know the reason for that. I have tried using only diamond operator (<>) and other methods in Stack Overflow.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
                    List<String> view = new ArrayList<String>();
            view.add("Grid view");
            view.add("chart view");



            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,View);


            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: try this tutorial : https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: Please don't offer voting advice or commentary in your posts. People are entitled to vote whichever way they like here, as long as they do not focus on one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
String[] data= {"Grid view","chart view"};
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data);

spinner .setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

then you could get selected items position on

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {    }
```

Answer (score 3):

change this code

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,view);//insted of View use view
```

Comment: view is the name of my array list bro

Comment: yes but you declaration is wrong you declare View actually pass view that name of your arraylist

Answer (score 1):

use `view` instead of `View`

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,view);
```

Comment: view is the name of my array list bro

Comment: Check your adapter initializing  code . You are passing View instead of view.. View is a class, not your array List

Comment: Your code is working for me. Could you please share your layout XML

Comment: shall i share u in this comment

Comment: in your question

Answer (score 0):

Another workable example of your code

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        Arrays.asList("Grid View", "chart view")));
```

Answer (score 0):

spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_items,yourArrayList);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner:
            String str_type=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            TypeSelected = position;
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
}
```